# return value from php to batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file that calls a php script. The php script returns a value that I want to use in the batch script. The php script echoes the correct return value however I have not been able to find a way to capture the value to use in the batch file.

I have tried a number of variations on for loops without success. My batch script is as follows:

```
@echo off
Setlocal

"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hello.php

endlocal
```

This of course just returns "Hello." How can I set a variable in the batch file (a variable named retVar for example) to contain what is returned from this php call?

thank you,
Shimon

Comment: Have you tried `"php -f script.php | set bla=` ?

Comment: If it is printed to standard out use for. `for /f %A in ('time /t') do echo %A`

Comment: Print or return? `echo 33` is not the same as `exit(33)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
       '"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hello.php'
    ) do set "retVar=%%a"

    echo %retVar%
```

Use `for /f` to execute a command (in the `in` clause) and for each line in the command output, execute a block of code (in the `do` clase). For each line, the variable/replaceable parameter (`%%a` in sample code) will hold the line. In this case, as the output of the php command is only one line, it will be executed only one time, storing the php output line into the `retVar` variable.

`for /f` will, by default, try to tokenize the lines it reads, splitting in fields using spaces a delimiters. To avoid this behaviour, a empty list of delimiters is used, so all the line contents will be stored in `%%a`